# Using a pointer without assigning a variable memory address to it

Tags: c++, c

Check out the below code

```
  char *str;
  gets(str); // or fgets
  puts(str);
```

its an example program in c++. Actually I feel its not a good way of coding because we did not assign a memory location to the char pointer `str`. The book says `char array[10]` has a limitation of length whereas `char pointer str` does not have a fixed length, we can input as many `chars` as possible. But I believe pointers can never be used without assigning a memory address to it, as I have learnt in C.

I think this must be the right way of doing it,

```
  char a[100];
  char *str=a;
  fgets(a,100,stdin);
  puts(a);
```

Kindly make me sure. Is it a good way of coding pointers without assigning a variables memory address to it? or what are the best ways to do it. Let me know what happens if we use pointers without assigning a memory address.Thanks.

Comment: Seond example is correct. But you don't need `char *str=a;`

Comment: yes i agree @kotlomoy

Comment: You should try and avoid [gets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346598/gets-function-in-c) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it a good way of coding pointers without assigning a variables memory address to it?

No. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer has undefined behavior - ***never, ever do it!***

If you need a variable-length array, consider using `std::string` (for representing strings) or `std::vector` (for practically any data type) instead.

Answer (score 3):

1. Using pointers without initialization causes undefined behavior. It should not be used.
2. And also, `gets` is deprecated, because it's not safe, use `gets_s` or `fgets` instead, as in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is correct.  Using an uninitialized pointer causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I've always got in some sort of odd behaviors when it came to use uninitialized pointers.

I'm a **malloc-freak** in C language. In fact using an explicit arrays of char have always led to some weird outputting.

Plus the static pointers are not meant to be returned out of a function. you really don't want to do that.