# getting ╠ when printing in C

Tags: c, palindrome

i have search and found a solution but i cant figure it out why my code still not working, if i understand it right my check2 string not having '\0'.
im using visual studio
i know there is a better way to write and short then this but just tried to practice some things and tried to do it harder then its need to be.
im new to C so dont judge me :P
this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
A palindrome is a string that is same in both forward and backward reading.
Example:
   "madam"
   "racecar"
   "a man a plan a canal panama"
   "radar"
You will write a program that will test if a given string is a palingdrome or not.
Your program will ask the user to input a string and if the string is a palindrome program
will just print "Yes, it is a Palindrome", otherwise will print "No, not a Palindrome".

Please note that:
1. Your you need to check in case-insensitive way, that means: Madam or madam both should be
detected as Palindrome.

2. There can be (any number of ) spaces in between the words.
    "A man a plan a canal panama"
        OR
    "A     man    a   pla n a cana l Panama"
    both the strings must be detected as Palindrome.
3.There can be punctuations in between the words, for this assignments,
we consider only 4 punctuations,   . ?  ! and ,

Your program will just need to ignore them (treat them as space).
    "Cigar? Toss it in a can. It is so tragic."
    Should be detected as palindrome.

 *** For this assignment I will not write any instructions or guidance, you are free
        to implement it with your own way, you can use the string.h functions

    Good luck.

*/


int main(){
    char string [100];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", string);

    int isPalindrome = 1;  // assign 0 to this if the string is a NOT palindrome

    // write code to test if string is a palindrome

    char check1[100], check2[100];
    int i, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++, j++)
    {
        if ((string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z') || (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z'))
        {
            check1[i] = string[i];
        }
    }

    check1[i] = '\0';

    for (i = strlen(string); i < 0; i--)
    {
        if ((string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z') || (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z'))
        {
            check2[i] = string[i];
        }
    }

    i = strlen(string);
    check2[i] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; check1[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ((check1[i] >= 65) && (check1[i] <= 90))
            check1[i] = check1[i] + 32;
    }

    for (i = 0; check2[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ((check2[i] >= 65) && (check2[i] <= 90))
            check2[i] = check2[i] + 32;
    }

    printf("%s\n", check1);
    printf("%s\n", check2);

    isPalindrome = strcmp(check1, check2);

    // at the end you need to test
    if (isPalindrome){
        printf("Yes, it is Palindrome!\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("No, not a Palindrome\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

and this is my output:

```
Enter a string: MadaM
madam
╠╠╠╠╠
Yes, it is Palindrome!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

ok so now my code look like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
A palindrome is a string that is same in both forward and backward reading.
Example:
   "madam"
   "racecar"
   "a man a plan a canal panama"
   "radar"
You will write a program that will test if a given string is a palingdrome or not.
Your program will ask the user to input a string and if the string is a palindrome program
will just print "Yes, it is a Palindrome", otherwise will print "No, not a Palindrome".

Please note that:
1. Your you need to check in case-insensitive way, that means: Madam or madam both should be
detected as Palindrome.

2. There can be (any number of ) spaces in between the words.
    "A man a plan a canal panama"
        OR
    "A     man    a   pla n a cana l Panama"
    both the strings must be detected as Palindrome.
3.There can be punctuations in between the words, for this assignments,
we consider only 4 punctuations,   . ?  ! and ,

Your program will just need to ignore them (treat them as space).
    "Cigar? Toss it in a can. It is so tragic."
    Should be detected as palindrome.

 *** For this assignment I will not write any instructions or guidance, you are free
        to implement it with your own way, you can use the string.h functions

    Good luck.

*/


int main(){
    char string [100];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", string);

    int isPalindrome = 1;  // assign 0 to this if the string is a NOT palindrome

    // write code to test if string is a palindrome

    char check1[100], check2[100];
    int i, j, dess = 0, len;

    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ((string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z') || (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z'))
        {
            check1[dess++] = string[i];
        }
    }

    check1[dess] = '\0';



    /*
    len = strlen(string);


    for (j = 0, i = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
        if ((string[j] >= 'A' && string[j] <= 'Z') || (string[j] >= 'a' && string[j] <= 'z'))
        {
            check2[i++] = string[len - j];
        }
    }
    */

    for (dess = 0, i = strlen(string) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ((string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z') || (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z'))
        {
            check2[dess++] = string[i];
        }
    }

    check2[dess] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; check1[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ((check1[i] >= 65) && (check1[i] <= 90))
            check1[i] = check1[i] + 32;
    }   

    for (i = 0; check2[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ((check2[i] >= 65) && (check2[i] <= 90))
            check2[i] = check2[i] + 32;
    }

    printf("%s\n", check1);
    printf("%s\n", check2);
    for (i = 0; check1[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", check1[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; check2[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", check2[i]);
    }

    isPalindrome = strcmp(check1, check2);

    // at the end you need to test
    if (isPalindrome){
        printf("Yes, it is Palindrome!\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("No, not a Palindrome\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

but my output is:

```
Enter a string: MadaM
madam
madam
m
a
d
a
m
m
a
d
a
m
No, not a Palindrome
Press any key to continue . . .
```

why its say its not a palindrome?

Comment: `for (i = strlen(string); i < 0; i--)` never executes: the `i<0` condition is wrong. Should be `i>=0`. And should start at `strlen(string)-1`

Comment: `╠╠╠╠╠` is a magic numner, indicating a certain widely spread mistake in the code. There is a duplicate question, which admittefly I cannot find now.

Comment: ah, I think you are looking for this Question here @Yummosch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931221/my-output-has-some-weird-symbols-displaying

Comment: same symptoms, different cause.

Comment: ╠ is 0xCC in codepage 437, and [MSVC fills 0xCC to uninitialized memory to help debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714). That means you've accessed uninitialized memory. You can find tons of questions about ╠ and 0xCC here on SO

Comment: thanks guys idk why didnt find that post sorry.

Comment: @MukeshA No. I found that one. I am of course looking for an answer, which explains the special meaning of the magic number. (Oh and my nick does not contain "m"s.)

Comment: @phuclv That one is close and definitly helpful. But I am sure to have seen an answer which uses those non-alpha characters in the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

this loop is not executing at all:

```
for (i = strlen(string); i < 0; i--)
{
    if ((string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z') || (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z'))
    {
        check2[i] = string[i];
    }
}
```

because `i < 0` condition is a "continue" condition, not a "stop" condition. Besides, `i` starts outside string data.

So `check2` is never initialized, which explains the garbage.

The fixed loop is:

```
for (i = strlen(string) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Those reverse loop constructs are error prone. I'd suggest a forward loop and compute the reverse index in the loop, much clearer, like this:

```
int len = strlen(string);
for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
{
    i = len-j-1;   // starts at the last char, ends at the first char
```

in that case, there's no need to loop in reverse, since a forward loop achieves exactly the same result (there is no `break` or other index here)

Comment: that forward loop its much better but still i want to stay with my reverse loop
now i have changed all working but when i put MadaM its said its not a Palindrome
my code
for (dess = 0, i = strlen(string) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
 {
  if ((string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z') || (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z'))
  {
   check2[dess++] = string[i];
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems with your loop indizes and limits as pointed out by others.

Apart from that you have some problem with filtering for letters:

```
    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++, j++)
    {
        if ((string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z') || (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z'))
        {
            check1[i] = string[i];
        }
    }
```

First of all, you could use function `isalpha()` to check for letters.
Second, what do you think, happens to the spaces in between?
You simply copy any letter to your array `check` just in the same place as where it is in your input string.
This does not make sense.

You need a second variable for destination index::

```
    int dest = 0;
    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ((string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z') || (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z'))
        {
            check1[dest++] = string[i];
        }
    }
```

Similar for the other loop(s)

Comment: this is already better than my answer that fixes OP first issue... but doesn't fix the rest. Well, maybe we should close that question altogether with a duplicate link

Comment: Well, the dupe only tells that there is some uninitialized variable involved without solving anything for the OP. This would ask for an immediate follow up question "Where do I miss initialization ?"

Comment: with the answers here + the duplicate OP has it sorted out, and this question doesn't really adds value to the site.

Comment: Yes, if the answers are kept it should be sufficient

Comment: ohh you right didnt think about that, so i changed my code like all the advice here, when i print the strings its print the same, but when i put MadaM, its said its not a Palindrome.