# How to join two strings in C?

Tags: c

I have written this code but it's not working. It is showing some extra characters in the end. Here's the code:

```
// Program to concate/join two string
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    int i,j,n=0;
    char str[100],str2[100],str3[100];
    printf("Enter string 1:\n");
    gets(str);
    printf("Enter string 2:\n");
    gets(str2);
    for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        str3[i]=str[i];
        n=n+1;
    }
    for(i=0,j=n;str2[i]!='\0';i++,j++)
    {
        str3[j]=str2[i];
    }
    printf("The concanted sring is: \n");
    puts(str3);
}
```

[image: Here's the output]

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. Check if you are entering some special characters. Did you try other test cases?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of output, copy & paste the output and put in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In C language, a string is a null-terminated array of characters.

> It is showing some extra characters in the end.

Reason for this is that you are not adding null character at the end of string `str3` after concatenating `str2` to it. Add a null-character at the end of the concatenated string, like this:

```
str3[j] = '\0';
```

Also, you should **[not use `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)**. It has been obsoleted. Instead, use `fgets()`.

---

Additional:
Follow the good programming practice, make a habit of specifying `int` as the return type of `main` function.

Answer (score 1):

Terminate the `str3` string with `'\0'` after you finish the copy loop:

```
for(i=0,j=n;str2[i]!='\0';i++,j++)
{
    str3[j]=str2[i];
}
str3[j] = '\0';  // proper termination of the `str3`.
```

Otherwise the `str3`will continue till first random `'\0'` in the memory is encountered. That is why you get extra characters when you print `str3`.

Also read this: [gets() function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346598/gets-function-in-c) and

[Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Avoid `gets()` in your programs!

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of best string manipulation function "strcat()" to concatenate to strings easily. try using below solution :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char str1[] = "Hello" , str2[] = "There";

    //concatenates str1 and str2 and resultant string is stored in str1.

    strcat(str1,str2);

    puts(str1);    
    puts(str2); 

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
HelloThere

There