# I'm just trying to scan strings into an array. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

   const int NUM_VALS = 20;
   int i;
   int actualInput;
   char userString[actualInput][NUM_VALS];
   int matchCount = 0;

   scanf("%d", &actualInput);

   for (i = 0; i < actualInput; ++i) {
      scanf("%s", userString[i]);
      printf("%s", userString[i]);
   }



   return 0;
}
```

Output:

b'hellohi\x80\x07@\xd2\x05@\x9a\x16[\xea\xccp\xa6\x15\xf6\x18+\xbf\x87\x8a#\x14)\x05@\xfe\x7f'b'\x92\x1fk\xb3\xfe\x7f\xfe\x7f\x118\x08\xe8\x03\x0eY\x03k\xb3\xfe\x7f\xfe\x7f\xb2Y{\xe8C}8\r\x8b-u{\x8cx86_64'F-8sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/binsbin:/binTF-88tf8RELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/coreutils/libstdbuf.so64-linux-gnu/coreutils/libstdbuf.sols/libstdbuf.soout

I've tried some variations replacing userString[i] with userString in the scanf function. The result is outputting 50,000 inputs of my last string. I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: Currently your program exhibits undefined behavior since you read from `actualInput` before it is initialized. Also, do you mean to use variable-length arrays?

Comment: What do you expect `actualInput` value in `char userString[actualInput][NUM_VALS];` to be? The main problem is there. I'd suggest you reading some intro on memory management in C.

Comment: At the time `char userString[actualInput][NUM_VALS];` is declared, `actualInput` is unitialized garbage, so there's no telliing how much memory you're allocating. Also, NUM_VALS is the max length of each string, so it should be MAX_LENGTH or something more meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this sequence of code:

```
int actualInput;
char userString[actualInput][NUM_VALS];
int matchCount = 0; 

scanf("%d", &actualInput);
```

The first line declares a variable called `actualInput` but doesn't assign a value to that variable.

The second line declares a [variable length array (VLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) using the value in `actualInput`. Using the value of an uninitialized variable results in [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984), which basically means that after that point in the code, anything can happen. What's likely happening (based on your description of the problem) is that `actualInput` is either zero, or a small number, so you get an array that's too small to hold your input.

The last line (with the `scanf`) finally assigns a value to `actualInput`. You may be thinking that the array will resize itself when `actualInput` is changed. That definitely does not happen. In C, after a VLA is created, its size cannot be changed.

The solution is simple, rearrange the code so that things are done in the proper order:

```
int actualInput;
scanf("%d", &actualInput);
char userString[actualInput][NUM_VALS];

int matchCount = 0;
```

As a side note, you should really do some error checking to make sure that the user inputs a reasonable number, before using that number to create an array. For example

```
int actualInput;
if (scanf("%d", &actualInput) != 1 || actualInput < 1 || actualInput > 1000)
{
    printf("That is not a valid array size\n");
    return 1;
}
char userString[actualInput][NUM_VALS];
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant declare it as a 2D array then treat it as a normal array . 
each case should include only one letter but it can't be done automatically , I suggest you add this :

```
for (i = 0; i < actualInput; ++i) 
{
    gets(stri);
    for (k=0;k<strlen(stri);k++)
    userString[i][j]=stri[j];
}
```

Comment: `gets(stri);` has not been in C since C11.

Comment: it gets the job done , what they at least say at UNI

Comment: "it gets the job done" Which means they are teaching you per an old standard of C - not a professional approach to the language.  UNI is likely behind the times when it comes to C.  See [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359) and [gets() function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4346598/2410359).